# Подготовка данных для машинного обучения из csv c множеством столбцов

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Здравствуйте. Ранее задавал вопрос по подготовке данных для машинного обучения. Но теперь задача усложнилась. Данные в файле такого вида:

```
100;word;14;alice;59;?
200;any;35;?;?;?
6300;yes;?;myself;?;?
```

Если с извлечением категорий все понятно, то данные для обучения получаются в виде двумерного массива. Была мысль создать список строк, и помещать в него строки, полученные объединением каждой строки массива по столбцам (за исключением нулевого).
Т. е. взять строку из датафрейма. Объединить все ячейки в ней (кроме нулевой) c помощью `join()`. Поместить результат в строку. За тем следующую строку и т. п. А потом массив строк пропустить через `HashingVectorizer`.
Но хотелось бы узнать, нет ли уже реализованной штуки такого рода (в `pandas.dataframe` я что-то не нашел).
В первом столбце - категория. Во всех последующих - набор данных. Я думаю, что правильнее будет считать набор случайным (т. к. данные мне предоставлены именно в подобном виде).
Данные не гомогенны. В столбцах могут встречаться знаки вопроса (как заменка NaN), так и сами данные.

Comment: вы можете объяснить что у вас у в каждом столбце? или это случайный набор данных? Объединить выбранные столбцы в Pandas - очень просто, но я не уверен что вам именно это нужно...

Comment: Обновил сообщение.

Comment: эти столбцы случайных данных - они хотя бы гомогенные (я имею в виду тип данных) или в одном столбце могут встречаться и числа и строки?

Comment: Обновил сообщение.

Comment: Это не очень хорошо. Я бы поменял знаки вопроса на какие нибудь числа (которые не могут встретиться в ваших данных)

Comment: Тогда, можно заменить на какое-либо число меньше 0. Они в обучающих данных точно не встречаются.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59417/discussion-between-glassedmichail-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', sep=';', na_values=['?','NaN', 'NA'], header=None)
df[df.columns[[np.issubsctype(t, np.number) for t in df.dtypes]]] = \
    df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).fillna(-1)
df[df.columns[[np.issubsctype(t, np.object) for t in df.dtypes]]] = \
    df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).fillna('')
new = df.set_index(df.columns[0]).astype(str).add(' ').sum(1).reset_index(name='joined')
```

Результат:

```
In [55]: new
Out[55]:
      0                      joined
0   100  word 14.0 alice 59.0 -1.0
1   200        any 35.0  -1.0 -1.0
2  6300  yes -1.0 myself -1.0 -1.0
```